# Guice: Forcing a binding to be injected as a provider

Tags: java, guice

I'm looking for a way to force certain Guice bindings to be injected as providers only. For example, when there is a configuration like

```
interface ResultLogger {
    void log(String resultAsString);
}

class ResultLoggerProvider implements Provider<ResultLogger> {
    // ...
}

class ResultDisplayModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ResultLogger.class).toProvider(ResultLoggerProvider.class);
    }
}
```

I would like to have way to configure my module so that a class like

```
@Singleton
class ResultParser {
    private final Provider<ResultLogger> loggerProvider;

    @Inject
    public ResultParser(Provider<ResultLogger> loggerProvider) {
        this.loggerProvider = loggerProvider;
    }
}
```

can be injected just fine, but an implementation like

```
@Singleton
class ResultParser {
    private final ResultLogger resultLogger;

    @Inject
    public ResultParser(ResultLogger resultLogger) {
        this.resultLogger = resultLogger;
    }
}
```

should throw a RuntimeException which notifies the developer that `ResultLogger` is only available via a provider. The exception would ideally be thrown as soon as possible, e.g. during construction of the injector. I'm looking for an easy way to achieve this using the existing API in Guice 3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should not implement Provider at all and just have a

```
@Singleton
public class ResultLoggerProvider {
   public ResultLogger get() {...}
   // ...
}

@Singleton
class ResultParser {
   private final ResultLoggerProvider loggerProvider;

   @Inject
   public ResultParser(ResultLoggerProvider loggerProvider) {
      this.loggerProvider = loggerProvider;
   }
}
```

and remove the other bindings.

Comment: That seems like the most reasonable solution for my problem. I guess I was thinking "inside the box" too much by trying to use the Guice Provider class and API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that it isn't right way. I guess you need smt like

```
interface ResultLogger {
    void log(String resultAsString);
}
class ResultLoggerWrapper implements ResultLogger {
      @Inject @Named("day") ResultLogger dayLogger;
      @Inject @Named("night") ResultLogger nightLogger;
      public void log(String resultAsString){
           if(isDay()) {
                 dayLogger.log(resultAsString)
           } else {
                 nightLogger.log(resultAsString)
           }
      }
}  

bind(ResultLogger.class).to(ResultLoggerWrapper.class);
```

Comment: That's an interesting take on the problem, thanks. Unfortunately, for my case, this doesn't really work because I need to have those provider objects. I'm building a small framework to inject configuration values which are liable to change, so I dynamically build providers for them.

Comment: @dosendoc I steel thinking that you should do some wrapping instead of forcing your users use "pseudo provider".

Comment: Currently, my API allows me to write constructors like this: `@Inject public DatabaseLogger(@ConfigValue(DatabaseOptions.HOST) Provider<String> databaseHost) {  }`. I think this is reasonably clean and it is a big help when unit testing, as it makes it immediately clear which configuration values influence the behaviour of a class. It also allows you to easily swap in values for isolated testing without separately mocking some `Configuration` object.

Comment: @dosendoc It's not my project, so do as you want) But I believe this is wrong way. You should use provider only for providing and prevent all other usages.

Answer (score -1):

It should work to bind Provider instead of ResultLogger. That is in your module

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Provider<ResultLogger>>(){}).to(ResultLoggerProvider.class);
```